# How can I set the JPEG Quality programmatically in a Drupal 7 installation profile?

Tags: drupal-7

By default the "JPEG quality" is set to 75% at "/admin/config/media/image-toolkit" in a Drupal 7 site. I find myself regularly setting this near or at 100% so I'd like to include that setting in my personal installation profile.

I thought this may be in the variables table, but I don't see anything that looks promising. I'm not even sure this is a core feature — part of Image Cache or IMCE? Any ideas on how to set this programmatically during the install?

Answer (score 0):

I found the right variable to set. Easy!

```
  // Set JPEG image quality to 100% by default
  variable_set('image_jpeg_quality', 100);
```